# Translate a min(max()) from CSS to SASS

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to make a resizable text, like a fluid text for a heading.
I can do so in css with

`font-size: min(max(1rem, 4vw), 22px);` but It does not allow me to translate this to SASS, it gives me a compile error

```
Compilation Error
Internal Error: Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'vw'.
```

How can I achieve the fluid text in sass? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of sass compiler are you using? When I used your line on SassMeister it compiles normally, because the line contains no SASS features: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/special-functions#min-and-max

Comment: is not really answering the question but maybe clamp will work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp

Comment: I guess your compiler needs to be updated. I guess it inpretes `min()` and `max()` as functions, since they share the same syntax (`function()`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that sass will attempt to interpolate the min max expression, but cannot do so because the units are mixed.

Best solution i have found for this is to escape the functions to ensure sass does not recognize and process them:

```
font-size: m#{i}n(m#{a}x(1rem, 4vw), 22px);
```

this should work for any sass compiler old or new and will output the clean expression without the compiler throwing errors.

Comment: I haven't found a better solution, the documentation is poor in this regard imo, here is the official sass docs on max: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/calculations#min-and-max